# What is RNAV transition and what is the difference between RNAV transition and RNAV STAR

Tags: ifr-navigation, sid-star, rnav

Can someone explain what is RNAV transition and what is the difference between RNAV transition and RNAV STAR. Because sometimes both types of procedures are published for an airport and I don't know what is the diference between those both types.

Comment: https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/pcg_html/glossary-s.html#%24SEGMENTS%20OF%20A%20SID/STAR

Comment: @randomhead Can you turn that into an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Your Question**: "Can someone explain what is RNAV transition and what is the difference between RNAV transition and RNAV STAR. Because **sometimes "both types" of procedures are published** for an airport and I don't know what is the diference between those both types." *(emphasis is mine)*

On an RNAV STAR the Transition Fix (there could be several for the same STAR) is the beginning of the transition from enroute to the terminal arrival portion of the procedure, see  ([SEGMENTS OF A SID/STAR](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/pcg_html/glossary-s.html#%24SEGMENTS%20OF%20A%20SID/STAR)) in the Aeronautical Information Manual, as noted by @randomhead in the comments to the question.

At certain airports/terminal areas, because of the complexity, volume of different routings, and for clarity purposes the "Transition" routings and "Arrival" routings are published separately.  At many locations both are published on the same page (or front and back of the same page).

Below is an example of an RNAV Star where both the "Transition" and "Arrival" parts of the STAR are published (separately).

The first image is the clearance a specific aircraft was given into KLAX (from FlightAware data). Note the routing into KLAX is **GABBL** (an RNAV Transition fix) to **HLYWD** (an RNAV fix where the Arrival portion begins).

[image]

The next  image is the **Transition** showing the GABBL Transition RNAV fix

[image]

The next image is the **Arrival** beginning at HLYWD and ending at SEAVU.

[image]

Comment: You can always identify a transition leg because the line is thin.  Once you cross the beginning of the common segment, the line become thicker and.  The beginning of the common segment start at HLYWD in this example.  On Jeppesen plates, the transition lines are dotted and the common segment is solid.  This is true for both SIDs and STARs

Answer (score 3):

An RNAV STAR will have one or more transitions that you have to file over to begin flying the STAR. The [CHPPR ONE STAR](https://skyvector.com/files/tpp/2205/pdf/00026CHPPR.PDF) to KATL has four transitions: BBABE, LEMKE, MTHEW, and RUTTH. When flight planning into KATL from the northwest (provided your aircraft qualifies per the notes) you would choose one of the transition fixes to begin flying the STAR.

Please also note that two of the four transitions are only for use by departures off of specific airports. BBABE and LEMKE are only used by departures off of KHSV and KCHA (respectively).

Comment: The first fix of the arrival portion is often a (null) transition itself.  Ditto for the last fix on a departure.